# How to make data change on click Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

```
<td> //here i need click button
  <v-btn icon v-for="bank in order.banks" :key="bank.bankIndex">{{bank.tittle}}</v-btn>
</td>


<td> // here it is necessary that only one price of clicked bank appears
  <div v-for="bank in order.banks" :key="bank.value">
    {{bank.currency}} {{bank.value}}
  </div>
</td>
```

here is part of my code. what i want: when click on the left button there on right side of table will change information. i thought i can do this through data() and v-model just create one object and write inside information about click  **BUT** i have a table with 100+ items and every item need same function.

Comment: You say you tried something and it didn't worked. Show the code!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do that is to create a function that will be triggered on button click.

```
<v-btn icon v-for="bank in order.banks" :key="bank.bankIndex" @click="setNewData(bank)">{{bank.tittle}}</v-btn>
```

```
methods: {
  setNewData(bank) {
    // make your changes here...
  }
}
```